# Can't access the jupyter notebook located in remote server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

First of all, all the answers from similar questions don't work at all, so I have to start a new thread.

In the server, I set the jupyter notebook config file into:

```
c.NotebookApp.ip='0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:fafa53ef8ee5:db912e1017919f9e4f2b154c026722e2b6934a0b'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8899
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' 
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
```

Then I start the jupyter notebook in the server:

```
[I 2021-07-22 12:26:27.244 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/<myname>/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-07-22 12:26:27.244 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/<myname>/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 12:26:27.250 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/<myname>
[I 12:26:27.250 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
[I 12:26:27.250 NotebookApp] http://<server_name>:8899/
[I 12:26:27.250 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Using netstat -anp command on the server, I found the server is listening to this port:
[image]

Now, in my local computer browser, I typed the website url  <server_ip>:8899, but doesn't work:

This site can’t be reached.
The connection was reset.

I also tried in my local computer

```
telnet <server_url> 8899
Trying <server_ip>...
Connected to <server_url>.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

which shows the server can be communicated from the outside through port 8899, isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure that port is open on the remote server?

Comment: @mcsoini, yes, when I start the jupyter notebook, I use "netstat -anp" to check the opened port, and the 0.0.0.0:8899 is shown, I guess it is opened correctly.                                                      
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8899            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      86140/python

Comment: what other question do you mean? Show links in question (not in comment) so we will know what doesn't work and we will no waste time for these solutions. And if other solutions gives you error messages then you should show them in question - it can help to see where can be the problem.

Comment: Results shows `0.0.0.0`. Did you run `netstat -anp` on server ? You should check from local computer if this port can be accessed. Server may listening but routers and firewalls (between server and your computer) may block it - and you can't access them to change it. What server do you use? You should check with port 80 which is used by all HTTP servers and usually routers don't block it.

Comment: @furas, Thanks. Yeah, I run the netstat -anp on server.   I just checked from my local computer that telnet <server_address> 8899 shows: Trying <server_ip>...
Connected to <server_address>.   This shows that the server is listening to outside through port 8899, right?

Comment: yes it is listening - if you would send `GET /` (and press ENTER two times) then maybe it would send back some HTML.

Comment: you could also check it with `curl http://<server_name>:8899/` or `wget http://<server_name>:8899/` and it could download HTML - if it has no problem with connection. You could check it on local and on server. You could also observer messages on server to see if it display some error message when you try to connect from local.

Comment: @furas, I tried curl http://<server_url>:8899/
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: @furas, When I tried curl a closed port, it gives me some different outputs. curl http://<server_name>:8900/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <server_name> port 8900: Connection refused

Comment: did you get any error on server? It seems it tries to redirect it to other address and it makes problem. As I remeber Juputer on local redirects to url with `token` - `http://<server>:8899/?token=...` and later again to `http://<server>:8899/tree` and maybe it makes problem because some other settings on server try to redirect it to something else and it create some loop and it has to reset connection to stop it. But I don't know what can makes this problem.

Comment: @furas, sadly no, in the terminal where I starts my jupyter notebook, no message is shown.    Maybe the server is redirecting my request to other places. The server is maintained by the university IT department and I don't have the root priviledge, so I may need to ask them about this. Still, thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe server already use `8899` for some other service - you should check with different ports - especially 80.

Comment: If you're able to ssh into the remote server you can also use SSH port forwarding to essentially map 8899 to 22. That's how I used jupyter for longest time in a similar university setting.